# PYQT Taking a screenshot of a hidden QWidget

Tags: pyqt

I have a QTabWidget with different tabs.
I want to take a screenshot of a hidden tab.

I found out how to create a screenshot of the tab if it's selected now.
The problem is that I want to be able to do that even if another tab was selected.

Comment: You should be able to do it with [`render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render-1), but you have to be sure that the widget has been properly resized and its layouts activated before that, otherwise you'll probably get an improper size. This normally happens as soon as it has been shown the first time, but if the QTabWidget has been resized in the meantime you might need to force its resizing (and probably by invalidating the layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple in the end, I hope it would help someone if he needs to.

To capture a screenshot of a widget you have in your application, even if it's not currently visible.
For example if you have a number of tabs in your QTabWidget:

```
# tabs_hash is a dictionary of the widgets we have in the QTabWidget,
# or any widget we have in the application we want to print
for name in tabs_hash:
    file = f'{name}.jpeg'
    tabs_hash[name].grab().save(file)
```